# Added javascript and now links don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added javascript to detect when a link is clicked, which works properly, however now the links aren't working (ie. they don't take the user to the linked page).

HTML:

```
<div class="designflow" style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:15px;margin-top:0px;float:left; font-size:18px; color: gray; height:150px; width:150px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:inline-block;"> 
<a href = "/manufacturing/" class = "designflow" id = "manufacturing">
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}pinax/images/manufacturing.png" width = "150px" style=margin-bottom:0px;" alt=""><br>
<p style="position:absolute;bottom:25px;padding-left: 0px; padding-right:0px; width:150px;text-align:center;">Manufacturing</p></a>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery( 'div.designflow a' )
    .click(function() {
        do_the_click( this.id );
        return false;
    });
function do_the_click( designstage )
{
    alert(designstage);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what return false does. If you still want the default behavior just get rid of that line.

Comment: Why are you doing `return false;` in the first place? Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The click handler disables them due to returning false

When you return false from an event handler you tell the runtime to stop processing it. This also includes to stop the default action. In this case to stop the link from being a link.

if you remove the 'return false' line. Then the link will work as a link usually does again

```
jQuery( 'div.designflow a' )
    .click(function() {
        do_the_click( this.id );
    });
```

however taking from the name of the methods you probably do want to return false and then handle the relocation in the event handler.

In JavaScript you can navigate to a new url like this:

```
window.location = newUrl;
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to elaborate on why? I believe the answer explains both what's wrong and how to fix it but I'd like to improve it if you think something is missing

Answer (score 2):

Its because you write `return false` in function, if you want to write it you must redirect page  to link address from javascript

Example

```
jQuery( 'div.designflow a' )
    .click(function() {
        do_the_click( this.id );
        window.location="/manufacturing";
return;
    });
function do_the_click( designstage )
{
    alert(designstage};
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By returnin false inside your event function you're explicitly suppressing the normal behaviour of the event. You should return true instead so that the event is processed normally by the browser after executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the `function` to return true

```
jQuery( 'div.designflow a' )
    .click(function() {
       do_the_click( this.id );
       return true;
    });
```